# How to Choose the right Sorting Algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

As we have many Sorting algorithms,I wanted to select the proper sorting algorithm for my case.

For Ex:Insertion sort is best for Small case of numbers ,whereas Merge sort is best suited for Large case of numbers.

I dont know what is that small range of numbers means .i.e 1-100 or 1-1000 or so.

Probably what is the best case for sorting a list of numbers where the same set of numbers are present present repeatedly.I am planning to store it in a hash and then store the elements accordingly .

Whether doing in through hash is a better way or Using some sorting algorithm is the best way

Comment: What types of data are these elements? Strings? What type of data structure are you using? What sorting algorithms have you looked at?

Comment: I suggest that you study the help center to understand what makes up good questions. Your question sounds like you are hoping that you can just throw your homework at other people and they do all the heavy lifting for your. And why should we know why some other group decided to use a certain algorithm?! Besides: if it is really true that your data set contains only 5 or 10 different entries, but those many thousand times ... then any sorting algorithm is a waste of time. Because then you would first scrub your input data and forget about the thousands of duplicates.

Comment: @Ceelos these elements are Strings and i normally use Merge Sort ,as it contains a time complexity of O(nlogn).But as here it contains the same data again and again ,So i don't know whether there is any better algorithm to do it

Comment: @Jägermeister First of all its not my homework.I am a beginner to data Structure and i know all kind of sorting algorithms,but i dont know in which situation i need to use which algorithm,So i need help in choosing from you people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But as here it contains the same data again and again

If you add some elements to already sorted array(list), then you have only small number of inversions. In this case insertion sort will work rather fast.

Alternatives - **natural** [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort)  or [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)(if implementation is available for your language) - these ones will behave good in all cases, including unsorted arrays.

Comment: but maintaining as Hash ,whether it will help ?

Comment: If I understand your usage scenario right, then answer is no. Hash is useful for fast search, not for sorting